# Как извлечь параметры headers c multi curl?

Tags: php, get, header, response, php-curl

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();     
    $connectionArray = array();
    foreach($urls as $key => $url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        $connectionArray[$key] = $ch;
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    }   while($running > 0);

    foreach($connectionArray as $key => $ch) {
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    }
```

Код показывает полученный header(хотя нигде нет echo, print...).
Как мне из него извлечь данные location?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодится:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();     
    $connectionArray = array();
    foreach($urls as $key => $url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        $connectionArray[$key] = $ch;
    }

    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    }   while($running > 0);

    foreach($connectionArray as $key => $ch) {
        $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
        $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $headers = substr($content, 0, $curl_info["header_size"]);

        preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!", $headers, $matches);
        $url = $matches[1];

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);
```